# How to restart/reset a program automatically after stop block

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

I have a program that uses the colour sensor to progress that program. The colours are in a certain order. If the wrong colour is detected, the program stops.

I want to restart the program from the beginning automatically if at any point the wrong colour is detected. Please note that I already have a loop encompassing the entire program if the colours are detected in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

> Please note that I already have a loop encompassing the entire program if the colours are detected in the correct order.

How about creating another loop for the failure case?

```
Start loop 1 (correct order)
Start loop 2 (wrong order)
Initialization
Check for colours
  If correct order
    Do something
    End loop 1 (correct order)
  Else
    Do some other thing (or not)
    End loop 2 (wrong order)
```